# Using Java, How can I list and print all Queries in a MS-Access 2003 mdb file?

Tags: java, ms-access-2003

I am able to create a java.sql.Connection object and get table data:

```
DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();

String [] tableTypes = {"Table"};
ResultSet rs = metaData.getTables(null, null, null, tableTypes);

if (rs != null) {
   while (rs.next()) {
      String tableName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
      // Do some further table analysis
   }
}
```

How do I get the Queries saved in the mdb file as well? (specifically, their names, and the SQL statements that they are made of)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/):

```
Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("access.mdb"));
for (Query query : db.getQueries()) {
    System.out.println(query.getName() + ": " + query.toSQLString());
}
```

Comment: This is perfect - Thanks!